# Some questions about the site's user interface.

Tags: support, user-interface

First, is there a way to insert line-breaks into a comment? This is often frustrating me because the comments are sometimes quite unreadable without line-breaks.

It would be also nice if [Enter] didn't submit the comment; this still surprises me sometimes and makes me add unfinished comment. *(I don't believe it can be changed though).*

More generally, is there some nice FAQ or other resource where one can learn everything about the site's user interface?

Comment: You may want to try modifying Tim's greasemonkey script posted [at meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66646/146482)

Comment: Thank you; but fortunately Input methods, spellcheckers and such aren't really a problem for me. And after reading the reasoning about [Enter] at SO (that comments should behave like chat), I think I am even starting to like the feature :-)

Comment: my point was you could probably use that script as a starting point to catch and ignore `Enter`. Yeah, I'm also starting to get used to it...

Comment: @Tobias: yeah, I understood that. I was just saying that the technical reasons are not really issue for me (at least right now). It's just a matter of habit.

Answer (score 3):

I think the theory is that if a 'comment' is long enough and has enough structure to require paragraphs (i.e. line breaks), then it should really be answer.

Personally, I quite like that it just takes [Enter] to submit comments. This is a recent change in the user interface of this site, and makes comment writing a bit quicker, in the case where one leaves many short comments (as I often do). [Shift-Enter] still gives you a normal line-break (only visible in the editor).

Finally, [the set of `faq`-tagged questions on Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) you may find quite helpful. These are generally large community-wiki style questions detailing various aspects of StackExchange sites, dating back to the early days of StackOverflow (but updated a lot since).

Comment: I don't get that theory. Comments often address specific parts of answers or questions and don't really make sense as a separate answers. E.g. this one of mine. But leaving more short comments solves the problem, I guess.
Also the [Shift-Enter] is useful. Thanks for all the tips!

Comment: @Marek: No prob. I can see why you're not a fan of it. Especially if you come from a background of using forum/thread-based sites where comment-replies are on equal footing with answers. I think if you ask the StackExchange designers, they'll say it's all part of the philosophy/design...

Answer (score 1):

> First, is there a way to insert line-breaks into a comment?

No there isn't.

> It would be also nice if [Enter] didn't submit the comment; this still surprises me sometimes and makes me add unfinished comment.

[Pressing Enter in comment box unexpectedly submits form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form)

> More generally, is there some nice FAQ or other resource where one can learn everything about the site's user interface?

You may ask a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Thank you. So I gather meta.SO is the main site to ask about all of SE? Kind of strange.

Comment: @Marek: Since meta.SE was already occupied for SE 1.0 sites.